# How to select first option in select?

Tags: angular

I'm using this and i added selected in first option but its not working. Any suggestion?

```
<select class="select-dropdown" [(ngModel)]="selectedTickeDecisionType" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
    <option value="" selected>Odaberi tip odluke</option>
    <option *ngFor="let decisionType of lovData.tticketdecisiontype" value="{{decisionType.code}}">{{decisionType.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What option is selected? Perhaps the option specified in your model?

Comment: i added in html  selected attr on first option

Comment: I see that, but what is your definition of not working? Is another option selected, and is that option maybe defined in your model before you load your page?

Comment: nothing is selected... and also i checked in html also nothing selected, also selected is not recognized in html

Comment: This question is asked over and over again. Use ng-options instead of ng-repeating your options, and, in the controller, set the value of $scope.selectedTickeDecisionType to the option you want to pre-select. Read the documentation.

Comment: im using angular 2 there is no scope

Comment: Oh, sorry. Misread that. The principle is the same though: select the option you want by initializing the selectedTickeDecisionType in the component to the code you want to select.

Comment: i added in html for default option to be selected but its not working..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When `selectedTickeDecisionType` is initially `null`

```
[ngValue]="null"
```

on the first `<option>` should do what you want:

```
<select class="select-dropdown" [(ngModel)]="selectedTickeDecisionType" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
    <option [ngValue]="null" selected>Odaberi tip odluke</option>
    <option *ngFor="let decisionType of lovData.tticketdecisiontype" value="{{decisionType.code}}">{{decisionType.name}}</option>
</select>
```

You might need `[ngValue]="decisionType.code"` on the other options to make this work properly (I haven't tried mixing `value` and `ngValue` myself yet).

Comment: i used your code...but it appears in select only if i remove ngModel, but i need ngModel ofc.

Comment: `ngValue` is not supposed to work without `ngModel`, therefore it's difficult for me to tell what's going on.

Comment: hmm so what can i do then?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/oGdLfBMPpHm5GF8fzAPP?p=preview. Seems `selectedTickeDecisionType` needs to be explicitely initialized to `null`. https://plnkr.co/edit/oGdLfBMPpHm5GF8fzAPP?p=preview

Answer (score 4):

```
<option
 *ngFor="let decisionType of lovData.tticketdecisiontype; let i = index"
 [ngValue]="decisionType.code"
 [attr.selected]='i>0 ? "selected" : null'>
  {{decisionType.name}}
</option>
```

Comment: i want that default option to be selected ..its before ngFor